# Can't finish a front car bumper grille

Tags: modeling

I have a problem: I model a front car bumper grille, but I can't finish it as I want. That's how this grille looks now:

[image]

That's how I want it to be:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

First make the rest of the bumper so that you know what shape you need to fit the grill into. Then you can use a Boolean modifier to trim away the parts of the grill that you don't want. Then move the slats of the grill forward and back to finish the shape.

It seems like you a very early in this build. Keep working at it and don't get frustrated.